# How to download waypoints from drone to Onboard-SDK?

Tags: dji-sdk

My use case is the following: I would like to retrieve waypoints set from a third party app in OnBoard SDK.

For the moment, I tried to set waypoints thanks to Altizure. Everything works just as expected in DJI PC Assistant 2 simulator. But I don't get the waypoints in OnBoard SDK (I am using ROS package to be more precise).

Is there some kind of way of requesting waypoints download in OnBoard SDK ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? can you please expand on your workflow? i.e. what is Altizure and how is it sending those waypoints?

Comment: Hi ! I solved my own problem [here](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK-ROS/issues/303). Altizure is just a mission planner amongst many others. I thought that Altizure was sending waypoints + camera trigger commands. But thanks to the piece of code I made (cf link above), I realized that Altizure was just sending waypoints and then triggering camera while UAV is performing mission (probably using GPS coordinates or elapsed time).